# How to explode a column in a pandas dataframe (python) and then stack it/multiindex?

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index, explode

I have a dataframe with a column I want to explode ("genre") and then reorganize the dataframe because I get many duplicates.

I also don't want to lose information. I get the following dataframe after using split and explode:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVWzg.png

I want to get a dataframe without the duplicates but keeping the genre column as it is. I thought of stacking it or making it multiindex but how should I proceed?

This database is not exactly what I'm using but it's similar in the column I want to work with:
https://www.kaggle.com/PromptCloudHQ/imdb-data

Comment: Could you upload the original data frame?

Comment: @ccommjin I found a similar database on Kaggle and added the link